# Is there any open-source 3rd party MDS (Meta Data Service) engine for Oracle ADF?

Tags: oracle-adf, oracle-fusion-apps, oracle-mds

Oracle has its own MDS Engine for Commercial ADF which support personalizations and customizations. ADF Essential which is free doesn't has this ability for personalizations and customizations. Is there any other way to achieve same free version of ADF with help of some open source framework?

Answer (score 1):

No, there is no such support available under open source licence.